# SQL Cut off string after certain number of spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a string that always reads as follows:

re-assigning LastName,  FirstName re-assigned the order to LastName, FirstName (Administrator)  Reason Code: Reassign order  Comment:

The name is always diffent but I only want to return the LastName, Firstname part on the first occurence so right after re-assigning. The spaces and everything is exactly how it appears when it is printer except the Lastname, FirstName is normally a name of course.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think its very hard to understand what your problem is..

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you're asking either...

Comment: I am triyng to just get the Lastname, Firstname part of this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @x varchar(max)

set @x = 're-assigning LastName,  FirstName re-assigned the order to LastName, FirstName (Administrator)  Reason Code: Reassign order  Comment:   '

select SUBSTRING(@x,14,PATINDEX('%re-assigned%',@x)-15)
```

Returns "LastName,  FirstName"

Is that what you need?